# copying value of void pointer C

Tags: c, avr

I have a problem with function which should print any type of integer on my KS0108 lcd. Here the problem is: when i want to copy `void* numb` value to `void* temp` in first swtich - nothing happens. in second switch when use `%I` get `0`. (value of `void* numb` is about `48` and type `_uint8_t`)
Code:

```
void glcd_WriteInt(void* numb, type type)
{
    void* temp = 0;
    int8_t buff[10];
    int8_t size = 0;
    int8_t flag = 1;
    int8_t sign = 1;
    switch(type)
    {
        case _int8_t:   memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(int8_t)); break; 
        case _int16_t:  memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(int16_t)); break;
        case _int32_t:  memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(int32_t)); break;
        case _int64_t:  /*memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(int64_t)); break;*/return;  //if want 64 - uncomment
        case _uint8_t:  *(uint8_t*) temp = *(uint8_t*) numb/*memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(uint8_t))*/; break;
        case _uint16_t: memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(uint16_t)); break;
        case _uint32_t: memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(uint32_t)); break;
        case _uint64_t: /*memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(uint64_t)); break;*/return; //if want 64 - uncomment
    }
    while(flag)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case _int8_t:
                buff[size] = *(int8_t*) temp % 100;
                flag = (*(int8_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _int16_t:
                buff[size] = *(int16_t*) temp % 100;
                flag = (*(int16_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _int32_t:
                buff[size] = *(int32_t*) temp % 100;
                flag = (*(int32_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _int64_t:
                /*buff[size] = *(int64_t*) temp % 100;      //if want 64 - uncomment
                flag = (*(int64_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;*/
                break;
            case _uint8_t:
                buff[size] = *(uint8_t*) temp % 100;
                flag = (*(uint8_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _uint16_t:
                buff[size] = *(uint16_t*) temp % 100;
                flag = (*(uint16_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _uint32_t:
                buff[size] = *(uint32_t*) temp % 100;
                flag = (*(uint32_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _uint64_t:
                /*buff[size] = *(uint64_t*) temp % 100;     //if want 64 - uncomment
                flag = (*(uint64_t*) temp /= 100) != 0;*/
                break;
        }
        if(buff[size] < 0){
            buff[size] = -buff[size];
            sign = -1;
        }
        size++;
    }

    if(sign == -1) glcd_Character((char) 45);
        glcd_WIntTab(buff, size);
}
```

I tried versions with `memcpy`, and like here: casts. It is suprising that this function was OK a few days ago.

Comment: Surprising that it ever worked; not surprising that it might fail in different ways. You're copying into the space pointed to by `temp`. `temp == NULL`, so that's unlikely to work out well.

Comment: may be you need a `union` instead of `void *`.

Comment: Since it was all working several days ago, why don't you go back to the version you checked into your VCS (version control system) when it _was_ working?  (Oh, you didn't use a VCS?  Now you know why you should always use a VCS if you are going to care about what happens when you change something.)

Comment: i have every version I did. But that version just stopped working. It was working while testing this function and stopped working while testing sth different.

Comment: change your `switch` to `temp = numb;` and leave the rest the same. Not sure what you were trying to do in that switch but it's not necessary, all you want to do is to reinterpret the memory being pointed to , which is what you do with the `*(int8_t *)ptr` expressions.

Comment: there are several problems with the code,  lets take a single example: buff[size] = *(uint32_t*) temp % 100;  this is treating temp as a unsigned int (in this case 4 bytes.  The max value is 4gig.  when performing a modulo 100, the result will not fit into a single byte of buff[].  buff[] is only 10 bytes, but 4gig needs 11 bytes

Comment: this kind of line, where the object type and the object have the same name is really bad coding practice, confusing to the reader, and clutters the symbol table.  suggest using unique names

Comment: this line: void* temp = 0; can never receive other than a pointer.  However the code is copying a value to where temp points.  this is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Also, temp IS a  pointer, so the proper initialization would be NULL, not 0.  there needs to be a malloc to have temp pointing to something real before copying anything where temp points.

Comment: 10 bytes of buff[] is sufficient to kepp 8 bytes long number. The max number of uint32_t contains 10 digits and I pack 2 digits into 1 byte of buff[]. So my buff[] is 2 times bigger then uint32_t can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have

```
void *temp = 0;
```

declared, and you try to write to a `NULL` pointer since you initialize it with `void *temp = 0`.

Even if you don't initialize it, it wont work because it wouldn't be a valid pointer, so either you allocate memory with `malloc` and assign it to the `void *temp` pointer, or use a union this way

```
union Type {
    int8_t _int8_t;
    int16_t _int16_t;
    int32_t _int32_t;
    int64_t _int64_t;
    uint8_t _uint8_t;
    uint16_t _uint16_t;
    uint32_t _uint32_t;
    uint64_t _uint64_t;
};

void glcd_WriteInt(void* numb, enum type type)
{
    union Type temp;

    int8_t buff[10];
    int8_t size = 0;
    int8_t flag = 1;
    int8_t sign = 1;

    switch (type)
    {
        case _int8_t:   memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(int8_t)); break;
        case _int16_t:  memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(int16_t)); break;
        case _int32_t:  memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(int32_t)); break;
        case _int64_t:  /*memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(int64_t)); break;*/return;  //if want 64 - uncomment
        case _uint8_t:  memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(uint8_t))/*memcpy(temp, numb, sizeof(uint8_t))*/; break;
        case _uint16_t: memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(uint16_t)); break;
        case _uint32_t: memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(uint32_t)); break;
        case _uint64_t: /*memcpy(&temp, numb, sizeof(uint64_t)); break;*/return; //if want 64 - uncomment
    }

    while (flag)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case _int8_t:
                buff[size] = temp._int8_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._int8_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _int16_t:
                buff[size] = temp._int16_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._int16_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _int32_t:
                buff[size] = temp._int32_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._int32_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _int64_t:
                buff[size] = temp._int64_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._int64_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _uint8_t:
                buff[size] = temp._uint8_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._uint8_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _uint16_t:
                buff[size] = temp._uint16_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._uint16_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _uint32_t:
                buff[size] = temp._uint32_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._uint32_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
            case _uint64_t:
                buff[size] = temp._uint64_t % 100;
                flag = (temp._uint64_t /= 100) != 0;
                break;
        }

        if (buff[size] < 0)
        {
            buff[size] = -buff[size];
            sign = -1;
        }
        size++;
    }
    if (sign == -1)
        glcd_Character((char) 45);
    glcd_WIntTab(buff, size);
}
```

I believe the union is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! I totaly forgot about unions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should not use names like `_int8_t`, I used them for the `union` so you could see more clearly what I meant. But it's confusing.

Comment: the 'enum type' function parameter is not defined in your code and uses very bad naming practices.